# Do larger numbers of hidden layers have a bigger effect on a classification model's accuarcy?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification

I trained different classification models using Keras with different numbers of hidden layers and the same number of neurons in each layer. What I found was the accuracy of the models decreased as the number of hidden layers increased, however, the decrease was more significant in larger numbers of hidden layers. The following graph shows the accuracy of different models where the number of hidden layers changed while the rest of the parameters stay the same (each model has 64 neurons in each hidden layer):
[image]

My question is why is the drop in accuracy between 8 hidden layers and 16 hidden layers much greater than the drop between 1 hidden layer and 8 hidden layers, even though the difference in the number of hidden layers is the same (8).